# "I made my username John95'" vs "I made 'John95' my username"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

Are these two sentences interchangeable?

- I made my username "John95"
- I made "John95" my user name.

Context: Let's say I created an account on ell.stackexchange.com for the first time in my life (so I didn't have a username here before), and I chose "John95" as my username, and I am letting the person listening to me know that.

Comment: They have the same meaning, and could also mean that you changed your username to John95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are exactly the same in meaning and both are perfectly natural sounding to my native AmE ears

Answer (score 0):

There's not much difference, but I prefer the first for a couple of reasons.

Firstly "end weighting" is the tendency to remember the last part that someone says. This means putting the information at the end of the phrase makes sense

Secondly, if you "make X Y" it tends to mean that you changed X into Y. In this case you changed your username into "john95" so the order "I made my username "John95" is preferred.